# Unable to know deselected items when using "Move Selection" short-cut deselected something on a Tree

Tags: java, zk

I'm using ZK 6.5.1.

Sometimes a tree may contains some logic, like do things when user select/deselect an item, this can easily done by listening event like this.

```
@Listen("onSelect = #tree")
public void onSelect(SelectEvent<Treeitem, String> event) {
    Treeitem ref = event.getReference();
    if (ref.isSelected()) {
        // do things when item is selected
    } else {
        // do things when item is deselected
    }
}
```

On the other hand, ZK provide function that user can using <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>Page Up</kbd>, <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd> on a Tree to "[Move Selection](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Data/Tree#Mouseless_Entry_Tree)". This action will also send out a select event about new selected item, **but not send events for deselected items**. Therefore, previous code snippets dose not works when user use these keys.

My questions are :

1. How should I do so I can know exactly which items are deselected when user "Move Selection"?
2. If not, can I disable these keys ?

Here's a SSCCE example if someone want to know. [Or in ZKFiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3ppvrj9/1-Move-Selection-hot-key-dosen-t-sent-event-for-deselect-items)

**Composer :**

```
public class TestComposer extends SelectorComposer<Div> {

    @Listen("onSelect = #tree")
    public void onSelect(SelectEvent<Treeitem, String> event) {
        Treeitem ref = event.getReference();
        if (ref.isSelected()) {
            Clients.log("Selected " + ref.getLabel());
        } else {
            Clients.log("Deselected " + ref.getLabel());
        }
    }
}
```

**ZUL :**

```
<div apply="mytest.TestComposer">
    <tree id="tree" multiple="true" checkmark="true">
        <treechildren>
            <treeitem label="A" />
            <treeitem label="B" />
            <treeitem label="C" />
        </treechildren>
    </tree>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is logical, cos in event-driven programming it is good practice
to send only one event per user action. But all the information you need
is inside the event.
See [here on zk fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3eh404v/1-How-to-findout-Items-deselected-by-key-in-Tree) how I improved you example.
I just add a few lines to the event method.

```
@Listen("onSelect = #tree")
    public void onSelect(SelectEvent<Treeitem, String> event) {
        Treeitem ref = event.getReference();
        Set<Treeitem> newSelection = new HashSet<Treeitem>(event.getSelectedItems());
        if (ref.isSelected()) {
            if (selected != null) {
                Set<Treeitem> deselected = new HashSet<Treeitem>(selected);
                deselected.removeAll(newSelection);
                for (Treeitem t : deselected) {
                    Clients.log("Deselected " + t.getLabel());
                }
            }
            Clients.log("Selected " + ref.getLabel());
        } else {
            Clients.log("Deselected " + ref.getLabel());
        }
        selected = newSelection;
    }
```

I use java `Set` and set-theoretic logic to compute a `Set` of deselected Items.

Comment: I do understand why ZK won't sent multiple events at once. However, the behavior still looks weird to me, I guess that's just because my code rely too much on `reference` rather than actual selected data. Thank you for pointing this out. +1 and accepted.